# Android ImageViews Causing Memory Leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, imageview

I'm the sole developer on an app for the company I work for. I'm new at app development and I've nearly finished the app but when I was testing, I noticed the heap size grows while navigating the app up to 3x the starting amount until GC runs and knocks it back down. I ran MAT and saw that it had to be something with bitmaps. I am currently changing the icons to an "on" state every time they are touched. This means I just changed the icons to a different colored image to give the visual appearance of being "tapped" such as below.

```
    ImageView callButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.callButton);
    callButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.call_on);
```

They are then turned "off" from onResume such as below.

```
    ImageView callButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.callButton);
    callButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.call_off);
```

I do this for every icon throughout the app. My question is whether this is causing the memory leak from creating so many ImageViews. Should I set them to null onDestory?

Comment: use fresco or glide instead of imageview

Comment: @quicklearner that's a completely non-sensical idea based on how he's using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need to set bitmaps to null in `onDestroy`.  Especially not if you're using images from resources, which references are kept to in `Resources` anyway.  What you may want to consider is using a `StateDrawable` and changing the state rather than switching `drawable`'s all the time, just for your own sanity. But this kind of usage shouldn't be causing OOMs unless you have a lot of images or other issues.

Comment: I implemented the StateListDrawables, which are great and help a lot, but I noticed that every time I tap on a spinner it uses about .1 MBs and grows the heap. Would there be a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Release your bitmaps  as soon as possible using `setImageDrawable(null)` like -

```
callButton.setImageDrawable(null);
```